# htaccess ErrorDocument 404 conflict with RewriteEngine On

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using the below in my `htaccess` file to strip out the `.php` extensions on my files. It works fine.

However, I also want to utilize `ErrorDocument 404 /index.php` to redirect any non existing urls back to the homepage. If I use `ErrorDocument 404 /index.php` alone in the `htaccess`, the redirects work fine. Also, if I use the below Rewrite code it successfully strips the php extensions. I would like both of these to work together, however.

For example, if a user enters "`www.domain.com/register`", they go to `www.domain.com/register.php`. But if they enter "`www.domain.com/something`", and `something.php` doesn't exist, then they redirect back to `index.php`. I've tried every permutation of both of these together in my `htaccess` to no avail. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

Answer (score 5):

Not sure what the problem you're having is exactly, but if I change your rules to this, it works for me:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php

Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

So instead of checking if the request isn't accessing an actual file/directory that exists, check that the .php version of that file DOES exist.

Comment: That's the key use `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f` rather than `%{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f`. +1

Comment: Awesome! Thanks, Jon and anubhava. I am a htaccess newb, so was just putting together conditions on found while searching. Make sense now that it is pointed out, but never would have gotten there on my own:) thanks again!